# codeigniter pagination url with get parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble setting up pagination on codeigniter when I pass parameters in the URL

if my url is like this : `search/?type=groups`

what should be my `$config['base_url']` for pagination to work?

if i set the base url to `search/?type=groups` the resulting url is `search/?type=groups/10`

which means `$_GET['type']=groups/10`

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that CodeIgniter does not function like that.
what I need is a method ( in the controller ) for each one of the options in "type"
so one option would be a method called :groups , another called entries etc etc 
each method refers to a different model class or method as needed.

I am trying to better understand OOP and CI ...a bit of adjusting to do ... feel free to comment and correct me if i am wrong.
thank you

Answer (score 105):

In pagination config:

```
if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
```

Your current `$_GET` vars will be shown in pagination links.
You can replace `$_GET` by another associative array.
This won't add a query string unless one already exists.

**Update:**
I just saw, if you go back from another pagination number to click on the first(1), CI does not care anymore of your suffix config.

To fix that use `$config['first_url']`.

e.g: `$config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);`

Comment: It is a shame CI didn't write `$config['suffix']` on their documentation @_@

Comment: if it is not working by placing in config, please add it to the controller page itself.

Comment: if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");  

This is wrong and lead to the point : ?per_page=20?per_page=40&param1=value1. Instead of you add the suffix, you should turn on reuse query string in config: $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 31):

The most up-to-date answer of this question is;

You should enable the reusage of the query string by enabling this configuration:

```
$config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
```

after that you should initialize the pagination:

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

> Added `$config['reuse_query_string']` to allow automatic repopulation
>   of query string arguments, combined with normal URI segments. - [CodeIgniter 3.0.0 Change Log](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#version-3-0-0)

Comment: This is perfect answer. Try this. all other answer also mark as right is also waste of time.

Comment: This answer should be voted and raised to the top. The most-voted answer might have helped in past but now it breaks at some stages.

Comment: this worked best for me, i took on another developers project who was using posts instead of gets for search and it was a hot mess but i found this useful once i switched everything from post to get

Comment: in my case it shows `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`.
URL Generate like `search/10&email=&mobile=11`. Now what should i have to do

Answer (score 5):

Here is my jquery solution:

Just wrap pagination links in a div like this:

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
```

than add the following jquery code:

```
$("#pagination > a").each(function() {
    var g = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?'));
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href+g);
});
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Great & Simple but not the best solution because if you don't leave the element, the link does not change.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using codeigniter 2 there's an option in `config.php`, `$config['allow_get_array']` - make sure its on TRUE.

Then set the pagination option `$config['page_query_string']` to `TRUE`.

And finally, in your case set `$config['base_url']` to `"search/?type=groups"`, the pagination will append the `per_page` query string after it.

It should work this way, you'll get the offset in `$this->input->get("per_page")`.

code strong!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same issue today. My solution is this:

1. Generate the pagination links and store them in a string ( `$pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();` )
2. Use regexp to find all links and add query strings

The regular expression code used is:

```
<?php
$query = '?myvar=myvalue';
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
$unique = array();
if( preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $pagination, $matches) )
{
    foreach ( $matches[2] as $link )
    {
        if ( !isset($unique[$link]) )
        {
            $data['pagination'] = str_replace($link . '"', $link . $query . '"', $data['pagination']);
            $unique[$link] = '';
        }
    }
}
unset($unique);
```

Works like a charm for me! What it does is:

1. Find all links
2. Replace unique links (since there is a previous/next links same link may appear more than once) with the original link and the query-string.

Then just assign the variable to the template that will be shown and use print $your_pagination_variable_name; to show the links with your query-strings attached!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do the same thing I was trying to do and I got it to work correctly by not setting a base url and just using this setup it kept me from having to manually editting the library

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['total_rows'] = 200;
    $config['per_page'] = 20; 

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the $config['suffix'] is the IMO best way to implement this because it doesn't require any extra processing as the regex solution.  $config['suffix'] is used in the rendering of the urls in the create_links function that's part of the system/libraries/Pagination.php file so if you set the value it'll be used in the generation of the urls and won't require anymore processing which means it'll be faster.

Thanks for the post, this saved me tons of extra, not needed, coding!

Answer (score 1):

Before line:

```
$this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
```

Replace this code below:

```
if(isset($_GET[$this->query_string_segment]))
{    
    unset($_GET[$this->query_string_segment]); 
}
$uri = http_build_query($_GET);
$uri = empty($uri) ? '?' : $uri . '&amp;';
$this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).$uri.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just see [this link](http://blog.boldsocks.com/codeigniter-pagination-get-parameters/).
Just update the modified pagination class and then add

```
$config['get'] = "?string=" . $_REQUEST['string']."&searchBy=" . $_REQUEST['searchBy'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. My solution is to modify Pagination and put it in application/libraries.
First i create

```
var $get='';
```

and find all "a" elements and add $get in the  `href="........'.$this->get.'"'>.......</a>`

Now in the controller or model input these line

```
$config['get']=(isset($_GET['search']))?'?search='.$_GET['search']:'';
```

That's it! i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

IN YOUR CONTROLLER:

$config['anchor_class'] = "class='link-pagination'";

IN YOUR VIEW:

```
$(".link-pagination").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr('href') + "?id=<?= $this->input->get('id') ?>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but realized that newer versions of CI have a suffix defined within the pagination class. Though it's still not in the documentation. No need to hack it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered with similar kind of problem, and based on the above answer here is what I have to do for customization according to my needs.

My URI was to be something like this:

```
base_url() . /search/?term=
```

So, here is what I have done:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url ."/search/?term=" . $_GET['term']
```

Answer (score -4):

Hope you'll find the answer on this page:
[LINK](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html#). Edit your answer back in if you can.